# Preventing grep from causing premature termination of "bash -e" script

Tags: bash, grep, exit, error-handling

This script does not output `after`:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "before"

echo "anything" | grep e # it would if I searched for 'y' instead

echo "after"
exit
```

I could solve this by removing the `-e` option on the shebang line, but I wish to keep it so my script stops if there is an error. I do not consider `grep` finding no match as an error. How may I prevent it from exiting so abruptly?

Comment: This is an observation meant only for consideration.  Perhaps the logic of this script should be thought through again.  If it is not important to find the string, why search for it?  grep's definition is such that one makes decisions based upon a string's presence or absence.  If you don't care either way, then it isn't important.  Also, it would seem `-e` presupposes you do care: so much so that *any problem* is catastrophic.

Comment: @AndrewFalanga I do care either way since I am actually analysing the content of `var=$(complex command | grep complex_pattern)` which may be null (in which case my program should not terminate). This is just a boiled down script which makes the problem occur. No metaphysical blackhole in the logic here, right? ;)

Comment: Knowing now that you intended to capture the output does clarify some things.  As presented, it was confusing to me.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```bash
echo "anything" | { grep e || true; }
```

Explanation:

- This will throw an error

  ```shellsession
  $ echo "anything" | grep e
  $ echo $?
  1
  ```
- This will not throw an error

  ```shellsession
  $ echo "anything" | { grep e || true; }
  $ echo $?
  0
  ```
- DopeGhoti's "no-op" version (Potentially avoids spawning a process, if `true` is not a builtin), this will not throw an error

  ```shellsession
  $ echo "anything" | { grep e || :; }
  $ echo $?
  0
  ```

The `||` means "or". If the first part of the command "fails" (meaning `grep e` returns a non-zero exit code) then the part after the `||` is executed, succeeds and returns zero as the exit code  (`true` always returns zero).

Comment: A slightly shorter version of the same that doesn't spin up `/bin/true` is:  `command || :` (so in your case, `set -e; grep 'needle' haystack || :`).

Comment: @DopeGhoti, `true` is a built-in in some shells (at least on `bash 4.3` on RHEL)

Comment: Not valid because if first command fails it will hide the error. A correct solution should return non zero if the first command in the pipe fails.

Comment: If you use `set -o pipefail` it does properly fail if the first command in the pipe fails. If this option is not used, it is normal that only exit value of the last command in a pipe defines the exit code of the pipe. If you do `set +o pipefail; false | true` (the default), you get success, if you do `set -o pipefail; false | true`, you get failure.

Comment: This hides true errors as well, i.e. errors when exit code is 2.

Answer (score 61):

A robust way to safely and **optionally** `grep` messages:

```
echo something | grep e || [[ $? == 1 ]] ## print 'something', $? is 0
echo something | grep x || [[ $? == 1 ]] ## no output, $? is 0
echo something | grep --wrong-arg e || [[ $? == 1 ]] ## stderr output, $? is 1
```

According to [posix manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55_14), exit code:

- `1` means no lines selected.
- `> 1` means an error.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it only suppresses the warning exit code (1) if grep does not find anything, yet it passes on true errors (exit codes > 1).  The other solutions here always suppress true errors, which is usually bad.

Comment: This is great, but suffers from one issue - if the `echo` command exits with 1, the whole line will exit with 0, not just the `grep`. It might be worth checking this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581991/58450.

Comment: if using bash, status of `echo` can be checked via `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`

Answer (score 28):

If you're using grep with `set -euo pipefail` and don't want to exit if no record is found (exit code = 1), but still want it to fail if it's another exit code, you can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

echo "anything" | { grep e || test $? = 1; } | { grep e2 || test $? = 1; }
```

The greps inside the pipes will ONLY ignore exit status = 1. This way you don't need to lose the benefits of using `set -euo pipefail`.

In this example I purposely included two piped greps that could fail to illustrate the concept.

Refer to myrdd's post [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627999/76673).

Comment: is this bash specific?

Comment: @CervEd The solution is generally applicable, but the `pipefail` option as motivation is bash-specific yes.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it only evades the 1-exit code failure of grep, not that of previous commands.

Answer (score 25):

Another option is to add another command to the pipeline - one that does not fail:

`echo "anything" | grep e | cat`

Because `cat` is now the last command in the pipeline, it's the exit status of `cat`, not of `grep`, that will be used to determine if the pipeline failed or not.

Comment: This worked for me when piping `find` into `grep` from Node.js.

Comment: Maybe this is a case of [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). If I need a *command that does not fail* I'd rather use  `:` (or `true`) as stated in @cyker [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330670/383404) which doesn't have any other meaning than that. The `:` symbol infact is just a alias for true (i.e. *don't fail*). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224910/1498118).

Comment: @a.barbieri Not useless; you can't use : in a pipe. If you would chain the command with a logical or, than yes, but that's not what this solution does.

Comment: I see. You are right, I didn't mension that I would use `|| :` in place of `| cat`, meaning I would not have done `| :`.

Comment: This won't work if using `-o pipefail`.

Answer (score 12):

Another option:

```
...
set +e
echo "anything" | grep e
set -e
...
```

Answer (score 8):

## Solution

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "before"

echo "anything" | grep e || : # it would if I searched for 'y' instead

echo "after"
exit
```

## Explanation

`set -e` or `set -o errexit`

> Exit immediately if a *pipeline* (which may consist of a single *simple
>   command*), a *list*, or a *compound command* (see `SHELL GRAMMAR` above), exits
>   with a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is
>   part of the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword,
>   part of the test following the `if` or `elif` reserved words, part of any
>   command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final
>   `&&` or `||`, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return
>   value is being inverted with `!`. If a compound command other than a subshell
>   returns a non-zero status because a command failed while `-e` was being ignored,
>   the shell does not exit.  A trap on `ERR`, if set, is executed before the shell
>   exits. This option applies to the shell environment and each sub‐ shell
>   environment separately (see `COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT` above), and may
>   cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.

Plus, `:` is the no-effect command in Bash.

Comment: It should be `{ grep e || :; }` rather than `grep e || :`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I have with most, and perhaps all the answers here, is that they are losing the true exit code ($?) and mostly returning $? as 0. **There is no way to differentiate if there was a match (exit code 0) or no match (exit code 1).** This solution addresses that concern:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "before"

exit_code=0
echo "anything" | grep e || exit_code=$?; if [[ $exit_code -ne 1 ]]; then (exit $exit_code); fi

echo "after"
exit
```

#### Explained

`grep`'s exit status is either 0, 1 or 2:

- `0` means there was a match
- `1` means there was no match
- `2` means an error occurred

Now, with the above solution:

- If `grep` returns `0`, the `test` is not run and returns the true $? exit code of 0, and also sets `$exit_code=0`.
- If `grep` returns `1`, the `test` is run and returns a fake $? exit code of 0, but we also sets `$exit_code=1` which can be used by future code to differentiate a match vs no match.
- If `grep` returns any other value, the `test` is run and returns the true greater than 1 error exit code that should correctly halt the script, we also set `$exit_code` appropriately, but that won't matter because the script will halt.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: Use `sed` instead of grep:

```bash
echo "anything" | sed -n '/e/p'  # prints nothing
echo "anything" | sed -n '/y/p'  # prints "anything"
```

Explanation: `sed` is forced to suppress any input (`-n`), except to print it (`p`) when it matches the regex.

The return value is 0 in both cases. Works on a modern Linux and an old Solaris 8.