# bash strict mode fails to assign pipeline output to variable by using grep with :space:

Tags: bash, grep, command

I hope someone has an idea about my issue.
The current minimal example fails, if I'm trying to assign a command/pipeline output to a variable due to the `grep "[[:space:]]"` expression for bash in the strict mode.

```
#/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
egrep -v '>' file | grep "[[:space:]]" | wc -l
var=`egrep -v '>' file | grep "[[:space:]]" | wc -l`
echo $var
```

`var=$(egrep -v '>' file | grep "[[:space:]]" | wc -l)` fails as well. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: *How* does it fail, exactly? What is the content of `file`? What are you expecting to happen, and what happens instead? Note that there appears to be a typo in your shebang line (should be `#!` not just `#`).

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you, I corrected the shebang but did not change anything. It fails because the echo statement will never be applied since the variable assignment failed. So the egrep execution works and returns a number or zero while the variable will not setted. The exit code is 1. The script should check for white spaces inside a FASTA file sequence.

Comment: The script works, if "file" contains white spaces inside a sequence, but fails if there is not white space inside the sequence. Obviously, bash fails to continue the pipe if "nothing" is passed.

Comment: You could try `var=$( { grep '[[:space:]]' file | wc -l || : ;} )` or simpler `var=$( { grep -c '[[:space:]]' file_no_space || : ;} )` - see for example [Prevent grep from exiting in case of nomatch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330660/prevent-grep-from-exiting-in-case-of-nomatch)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. White spaces are allowed inside a sequence header, but not inside the sequence ;-) headers are marked by > as the first character in a line.